# What software should I use to design infographics?

Tags: software-recommendation, information-graphics

I am designing an infographic for a charity but I'm unsure whether InDesign would be better than Photoshop even though I have little experience in it.
I would be happy to learn though.

What would you use also any tips would be great.

Comment: Thanks haven't seen this, it talks about which software to use and is pretty much my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither, use Illustrator. It's vector-based, so you can export your graphics as big as you want and it'll always look crisp. Indesign has (imho) better tools for formatting text, but Illustrator is superior when working with shapes - which, i presume, is what you'll be doing when creating an infographic